# ASP.NET MVC - Handle multiple models in the same view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-attribute-value

I am building an ASP.NET MVC application in combination with EF6 code-first, which serves as a configurator (like the cars one).

Consider having these models, as an example:

```
Office, Computer, Printer, Accessory
```

This means that you can configure **one** `Office` adding multiple items: N `Computer`, N `Printer` and N `Accessory` (i.e. mousepads, headphones, ...), finally getting the total cost of the office.

Each model has its own properties:

```
public class Office
{
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Computer
{
    public int ComputerID { get; set; }
    public Office MyOffice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public int RamGigabytes { get; set; }
    public int HardDriveGigabytes { get; set; }
}

public class Printer
{
    public int PrinterID { get; set; }
    public Office MyOffice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public bool HasScanner { get; set; }
    public string PaperSize { get; set; }
}

public class Accessory
{
    public int AccessoryID { get; set; }
    public Office MyOffice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

In order to handle this situation, I have written one `Office` controller, with three functions `Add, GetData, SaveData` for each  `Computer, Printer, Accessory`. All of them are called by AJAX POST calls in the View, returning a JSON string with some values (to simplify, I will write only the methods regarding the `Computer` class).

```
public class OfficeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComputer()
    {
        // Insert into database and return entity ID in a JSON string
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetComputerData(int ComputerID)
    {
        // Get data from DB and return it in a JSON string
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveComputerData(int ComputerID, string NewData)
    {
        // Calculate the new cost, update DB, and return the updated price
    }
}
```

This solutions means:

1. Having multiple functions in the controller, 9 in this case (3 x component)
2. Having to create N 'sub-views' in the view, 3 in this case (1 x component)
3. Having to manually create every single field in the HTML part of view, which has its own `id` so you can get/assign the value of the field
4. Having multiple functions in the JS part of the view (same as controller)

So, in the case you needed to add a property to one of the three models, you would have to:

1. Modify the `Get` and `Save` functions in the controller
2. Modify the 'sub-view' of the model, e.g. adding an `input` in the `div` container
3. Modify the JS functions in order to get/assign the value of the new field

There would be a lot of work to do just for one property and I don't think this is a good solution to be easily maintained in the future.

Is there a better solution to manage this situation? Something more dynamic, e.g. EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) model?

Comment: Who said EAV is more dynamic than relational DB? There is nothing you can do in EAV that's not possible in a relational DB. EAV is not bad, but it has disadvantages, for example: you have trouble for verification, indexing, querying and... . In such cases it's better to use a relational db that is fast, has reliable verification, indexing is as simple as possible, querying is way more faster and simpler to implement, ...

Comment: MasLoo you're right, but I believe that with EAV would be easier to manage the addition/removal of properties, especially in the view

Comment: If you want to migrate to EAV just because of changing couple of properties, Don't do that. In my experience working on such databases would become a disaster in the future. If you're using Entity Framework there is no worry, because you can use migration to Add/Remove properties with ease.

Comment: Actually in the UI is where i have found it does not pay to re-use components, and DRY is your enemy here for long term maintainability.  writing out each view specifically for each entity means down the road, you can change one entity and it doesn't effect others. or adding validation to the update views doesn't now break the getter views.  it might be tedious but it's simple and anyone can maintain it.

Comment: I'll go with partial views